# Measure the distance between turtles

Tags: python, function, object, distance, python-turtle

I'm doing a turtle race in Python, where we should reinvent the base code.
My idea was to create a podium and put the 3 first winners.
I managed to put the first winner in the podium, but now I don't know how to measure the distance between the turtles and find out who's in second and third places.
Any ideas?
This is the final output:
[the end of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVojm.png)

```
while True:
    turtle_winner = choice([maria, jaquina, toino, celeste, tia])
    turtle_winner.forward(randint(1, 5))
    if turtle_winner.xcor() > 70:
        break
turtle_winner.shapesize(3)
screen.ontimer(winner_podium, 250)
```

Comment: What are maria, jaquina, etc? Do you have a `Turtle` class with methods `xcor` and `forward` ? Can you show us the class definition ?

Comment: this is the creation of maria, and all the other turtles, the difference between them is the position on the screen ```maria = turtle.Turtle()
maria.color('red')
maria.shape('turtle')

maria.penup()
maria.goto(-305, 140)
maria.pendown()

for turn in range(10):
    maria.right(36)```

Comment: @SimonR, the `Turtle` class is defined in the turtle(.py) library that comes with Python.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example of how you might do this. I created a some turtles with random positions as a demonstration. Notice that i've given the turtles name attributes, otherwise your standings will just be the names of the objects themselves, which isn't very readable. The important part is how to sort the list of turtles by their `xcor` attribute, on the second-to-last line.

```
from random import random

class Turtle:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.xcor = random()
        self.name = name

a = Turtle('a')
b = Turtle('b')
c = Turtle('c')
d = Turtle('d')
e = Turtle('e')

turtles = [a,b,c,d,e]
final_standings = [t.name for t in sorted(turtles, key=lambda turtle: turtle.xcor)]

print(final_standings)
```

Output:

```
['d', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'a']
```

Hopefully that should get you started.

Comment: I'm new to python, and I'm not sure how to implement it, I will try to work around it, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Just FYI, if you `from turtle import Turtle`, you can instead make your `Turtle` class `MyTurtle(Turtle)`, a subclass of the actual `Turtle` class.  Then, your `key=lambda turtle: turtle.xcor` reduces to `key=MyTurtle.xcor`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(Turtle1.distance(Turtle2))
```

Comment: I thought about that, but all the turtles are inside ```turtle_winner = choice([maria, jaquina, toino, celeste, tia])```,and from what I read, ```choice``` only returns one ```turtle.xcor()```

Comment: why do you have choice? is the winner supposed to be random?

Comment: I was looking for ways to find one winner, and found this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54958054/how-to-declare-winner-in-python-turtle-race, on how to declare the winner, that I adapted to my own code, later I had the idea of a podium for the 3 winners.

Comment: You know the choice there is to randomly choose a turtle, right? The code after that makes it go forward a random distance. The choice *does* choose random a turtle from the list, not just the xcor.

Comment: yes, I know that it's not just xcor,my problem is that I only get 1 xcor, the 1º winner, maybe is too much for me at this level of knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I might go about this using a dictionary instead of top level variables to contain the field of runners:

```
from turtle import Turtle
from operator import itemgetter
from random import randint

STARTING_POINT = (0, 0)

RUNNERS = ["Maria", "Jaquina", "Toino", "Celeste", "Tia"]

def show_winners(field):
    return sorted(((turtle.distance(STARTING_POINT), name) for name, turtle in field.items()), key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)

field = {runner: Turtle() for runner in RUNNERS}

for turtle in field.values():  # simulate a race for example purposes
    turtle.forward(randint(10, 100))

print(show_winners(field))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
[(75.0, 'Celeste'), (53.0, 'Toino'), (52.0, 'Maria'), (44.0, 'Tia'), (24.0, 'Jaquina')]
%
```

The results include the distances so that you can see it's working.  If you only need the names, you can simplify the code along the lines of @SimonR's (+1) solution:

```
def show_winners(field):
    return sorted(field, key=lambda name: field[name].distance(STARTING_POINT), reverse=True)
```

And tossing the `import` of `itemgetter` (which was only there to avoid a bug in the case of a tie.)

```
% python3 test.py
['Toino', 'Jaquina', 'Tia', 'Maria', 'Celeste']
%
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a function for when each turtle finishes, in front of the `break`, and only when all of them finish, the podium shows. You also need a list for the places.

```
places = []

def onFinish(turtleName):
    places.append(turtleName)
```

You just need to put in the turtle name into the function, then it lists them all from 1st to last, which you can use for a podium.